# Crash when making Mopub ad banner visible

Tags: android, android-layout, mopub

I noticed that sometimes have crashes in my Android app while displaying an ad layout using Mopub SDK.
I've never been able to reproduce this issue and it never happened on my devices.

Here is the layout containing the ad banner:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
>   

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/list_divider"
    />

    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/ad_height"
    />        
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is where the crash happens:

```
View adsLayout = null;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  ...
  adsLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout_ads);
  ...
  if (adsLayout != null)
     adsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  ...
}

@Override
public void onBannerLoaded(MoPubView arg0) {
    if (adsLayout != null)
        adsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And here is the error bothering me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.requestFocus(WebViewClassic.java:6997)
       at android.webkit.WebView.requestFocus(WebView.java:2044)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2477)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2477)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2477)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2477)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2433)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2477)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2433)
       at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6487)
       at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6466)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:2609)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:708)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:708)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:708)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:708)
       at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8377)
       at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5575)
       at myapp.MyActivity.onBannerLoaded(MyActivity.java:129)
       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.adLoaded(MoPubView.java:247)
       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.nativeAdLoaded(MoPubView.java:287)
       at com.mopub.mobileads.CustomEventBannerAdapter.onBannerLoaded(CustomEventBannerAdapter.java:100)
       at com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobBanner.onReceiveAd(GoogleAdMobBanner.java:170)
       at com.google.ads.internal.d.E(SourceFile:1180)
       at com.google.ads.internal.c$e.run(SourceFile:214)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4788)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: HI @guillaume-tgl,I know this is old, but did you ever resolve it?  I have an app and have received a couple of crash reports caused by a nullPounterException on my MoPub AdView (banner).  It's weird, because I create the AdView once in onCreate & only destroy it in onDestroy, but in-between, sometimes trying to change it's visibility causes a nullPointerException.  Like you, I've not been able to re-create this issue at all at my end.  Thanks

Comment: To be honest, we've moved to Admob now and we don't have any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Move
 `adsLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout_ads);`
 to `onCreate(..)`.

You are getting a null pointer because `onResume(..)` is not called before `onBannerLoaded().`

Comment: Well, but if `onResume` has not been called before `onBannerLoaded`, `adsLayout` should be `null` and then `setVisibility` is not called, right?

Comment: AdsLayout is null that's why theybare never called.

Comment: Not sure to understand your answer. The issue does not happen when `adsLayout` is null since I check for it being null just before calling `setVisibility` on it.

Comment: I have this is onCreate and i m still getting the same error whenever i minimize the app